# Javascript event like window.onload for subsequent loads

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

We have a function that changes the iframe height at the window.onload event so we can adjust it to the page contents. The problem is that after clicking in an asp:menu the height its restored to its default and the window.onload event doesnt fire...so we need the event that would fire in subsequent loads (tried window.unload but didnt trigger)

The resize function cant be called on the asp:menu click because the window wouldnt have finished loading so the height calculation would fail...

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net AJAX exposes a client event model.  To execute code after the content is refreshed, use this to bind to the `pageLoaded` event:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoadedFunction);
```

Learn more about all of the ASP.Net AJAX JavaScript events here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386417.aspx

Comment: Thanks thats what i have been looking for...what about the case you hadnt ajax in the page? with only "plain" javascript?

Comment: @ase69s - In that case, `window.onload` would work fine.  The ASP.Net AJAX is enabling the content to update without the page reloading.  If you were to turn off AJAX, the page would have to reload to update the content (unless you completely re-designed your code).

Answer (score 1):

ASPNet uses background calls via AJAX and then updates the interface.
You should use servr-side code. Inspect the AJAX resolver you're using and look for its declared events. I'm sure there's one event that triggers after updating a webpage and you can attach an eventListener to it.

Comment: We could use updatepanel_load() in server side code but as in our solution you need to combine it with a hidden field in order to save the calculated height previously...Nevertheless the event rises at the start of the load not when it has finished so it couldnt be used in case you wanted to recalculate the height...

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with a similar script 2 years ago. I solved it using JavaScript in the newly loaded page's window.onload to call up to the parent document and execute the script. In the child page we had this script:

```
function goSetHeight(){
    if (parent == window) return;
    else parent.setIframeHeight('iframe_name');
}

// Edit: Forgot to add the window.onload call
window.onload = goSetHeight;
```

This script called up to the parent page where we had a script file included that had this function:

```
function setIframeHeight(iframename) {
    var iframeEl = document.all[iframename];
    var iframeWin = window.frames[iframename];
    if(iframeEl && iframeWin) {
        //var docHt = getDocHeight(iframeWin.document);
        //if(docHt) iframeEl.style.height = docHt + 30 + "px";
        iframeEl.style.height = iframeWin.document.body.offsetHeight + 30 + "px";
    }
}
```

Please note that the above function was written solely with IE in mind (it was an application specification), so to be usable cross browser it would need modification. The only real problem we encountered with it were 2 particular cases:

1. We had a couple of instances where the pages that were loaded in the iframe were from a different domain than the page holding the iframe. This causes a JavaScript security error because the browser thinks this is an XSS attack and denies it.
2. We also encountered several situations where the iframe was nested 2 deep. It was a hack-job work-around that I came up with that I was extremely unhappy about, but it worked while we refactored from classic asp into .Net. I have since lost the script that was used to perform the pass through, but it wasn't complicated, it simply performed a similar parent check and kept going.

Comment: We thought about this option too but as you said u have to put the script in each child page (more redundancy for changes :S) and the problem of external pages... at least its a valid option so there goes our vote ^^

Comment: @ase69s - This could be added in many ways. We chose to add it as an include in one of the existing includes so this script was added to all of the pages ex post facto. If you could find a way to remove such redundancy, it would probably work just as well. If your solution works adequately, I say go with it. I know we ran into problems with your idea because we had 3 pages that had slow load times so the menu_click was finished resizing before the page was finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

In the end we used a hiddenfield where we saved the height calculated in the window.onload

```
document.getElementById("iframex").value = document.getElementById("iframeheight").height;
```

...then in the Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e) we reassigned the height to the iframe: `iframex.Attributes["height"] = iframeheight.Value;`

This works for us (Because in our case luckily the page height doesnt change on each option selected) but doesnt resolve the original question about getting fired the window.onload event or something similar after subsequent loads in order to recalculate the new height...

We will wait so someone can give the best answer to this problem...